# Use JSON to pass variables to Twig

Tags: json, symfony, twig

In this line of code, Twig is passed an array of variable names and values:

```
echo $twig->render('index.html.twig', array('name' => 'John'));
```

However, rather than passing these in manually, is there a way of passing in some JSON with these key / values already set? E.g.

```
echo $twig->render('index.html.twig', array(array_from_json_file('names.json'));
```

Obviously, you could write an `array_from_json_file` function from scratch however I was wondering if there is already an in-built function that I should be using.

Comment: `json_decode($json_string, true)`

Comment: The "function from scratch" you are talking about would be 2 lines of code. fair enough.

Comment: @HorstJahns that always seems a very rational argument. However, I'm always loathe to invent my own code simply for the sake of it. The nice thing about library code is that it has unit tests (hopefully!), is debugged and has documentation. In this case it doesn't exist so I'm going to use the given snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided `array_from_json_file` returns an associative array, you can just pass its return value to the second argument of `render`.

```
echo $twig->render('index.html.twig', array_from_json_file('names.json'));
```

`array_from_json_file` would have to set the second argument of `json_decode` to `true` to get an associative array back

```
public function array_from_json_file($basename)
{
  // do not allow $basename to be user submitted ever
  return json_decode(file_get_contents("/path/to/{$basename}"), true);
}
```